# use awk to read a CSV with more than one char as field separator

Tags: awk

I have a kind of CSV file using `|#|` as separator

```
$ cat /tmp/dd.csv 
animal|#|mysize|#|weight|#|adult|#|age|#|length
0|#|cat|#|S|#|8|#|False|#|3|#|30.0
1|#|dog|#|S|#|10|#|False|#|4|#|46.66666666666667
2|#|cat|#|M|#|11|#|False|#|5|#|63.333333333333336
3|#|fish|#|M|#|1|#|False|#|6|#|80.0
4|#|dog|#|M|#|20|#|False|#|7|#|96.66666666666667
5|#|cat|#|L|#|12|#|True|#|8|#|113.33333333333334
6|#|cat|#|L|#|12|#|True|#|9|#|130.0
$
```

I would like, using `awk` to extract column 3, 1 and 4.

I get this:

```
$ cat /tmp/dd.csv | awk -F'|#|' '{print $3 ";" $1 ";" $4}'
|weight|;animal|;|adult|
|S|;0|;|8|
|S|;1|;|10|
|M|;2|;|11|
|M|;3|;|1|
|M|;4|;|20|
|L|;5|;|12|
|L|;6|;|12|
```

It "almost" work but I would like just:

```
weight;animal;adult
S;0;8
S;1;10
M;2;11
M;3;1
M;4;20
L;5;12
L;6;12
```

Comment: If the separator is `|#|` then it's not a CSV by any definition of the term as it's neither comma-separated nor character-separated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest with GNU awk:

```
awk -F '\\|#\\|' -v OFS=';' '{print $3,$1,$4}' /tmp/dd.csv
```

It is necessary to escape the special character `|`.
Output:

```
weight;animal;adult
S;0;8
S;1;10
M;2;11
M;3;1
M;4;20
L;5;12
L;6;12
```

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `|` as `FS` and after `$1` skip every other field:

```
$ awk -F\| -v OFS=\; '{print $5,$1,$7}' file
```

Output:

```
weight;animal;adult
S;0;8
S;1;10
M;2;11
M;3;1
M;4;20
L;5;12
L;6;12
```

Comment: I preferred the #Cyrius solution because usually if a CSV has complex `|#|` separator it's because we want to prevent Pbs in case e.g. `|` or `#` or both are present in some field.

Comment: @user3313834 makes sense but have you also considered how to deal with data that contains `;`s?